# Primary keys multiple

Tags: sql, postgresql

В Datagrip когда создаю таблицы выскакивает ошибка не понимаю с чем это может быть связано. Помогите исправить. Так как предыдущие вроде создаются. Есть корабль с primary key. И потом в таблице passenger выскакивает ошибка.[image: ERROR]

> ERROR: multiple primary keys for table "ship" are not allowed Позиция 100

```
CREATE TABLE Capitan(
    ID_Capitan INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CHECK(ID_Capitan > 0),
    First_name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    Second_name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    Third_name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    Passport_ID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Years_of_experience INT NOT NULL,
    Permission_to_operate_ships BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Ship(
    Number_of_ship INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Serial_of_ship VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name_of_ship VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Year_of_issue DATE NOT NULL,
    Cost_of_annual_maintenance INT NOT NULL,
    Act_of_cancellation INT NOT NULL,
    Status_of_ship VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ABC_Analysis VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Port(
    Name_of_port VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Country VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    City VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Latitude FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Longitude FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Cost_of_stay_in_port MONEY NOT NULL,
    Ship_unloading_cost MONEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Voyage(
    Voyage_number INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Flotilia TEXT[][] NOT NULL,
    Departure_date DATE NOT NULL,
    Arrival_date DATE NOT NULL,
    Total_distance FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Passed_passengers INT NOT NULL,
    Risen_passengers INT NOT NULL,
    Unloaded_tone FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Loaded_tone FLOAT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Client(
    ID_Client INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    First_name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    Second_name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    Third_name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    Passport_ID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Photograph BYTEA NOT NULL,
    Customers_internal_account VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Ticket(
    Identification_code VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Voyage_number INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Voyage,
    Serial_number INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Table_of_ports,
    ID_Client INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Client,
    Class_of_cabin VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Cabin_class,
    Number_of_ship INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Ship,
    Serial_of_ship VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Ship,
    Cost_of_ticket MONEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Ship_declaration(
    Barcode INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Voyage_number INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Voyage,
    Serial_number INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Table_of_ports,
    Name_of_cargo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Type_of_cargo,
    Number_of_ship INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Ship,
    Serial_of_ship VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Ship,
    ID_Client INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Client,
    Tonnage FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Cost_of_declaration MONEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Cabin_class(
    Cabin_of_class VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Number_of_ship INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Ship,
    Serial_of_ship VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Ship,
    Number_of_places INT NOT NULL,
    Cost_of_cabin MONEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Type_of_cargo(
    Name_of_cargo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Number_of_ship INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Ship,
    Serial_of_ship VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Ship,
    Number_of_goods INT NOT NULL,
    Cost_of_cardo MONEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Freight(
    Number_of_ship INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Ship,
    Serial_of_ship VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Ship,
    Tonnage_of_ship INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Passenger(
    Number_of_ship INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Ship,
    Serial_of_ship VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Ship,
    Number_of_cabins INT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Как и говорит ошибка у вас в таблице ship два первичных ключа (primary key). В таблице может быть только один ключ. Если вы хотите создать первичный ключ из двух полей, то не пишите после них primary key, а пишите после всех полей отдельную фразу primary key, объявляющую составной ключ. То же касается и foreign ключей из других таблиц на эту. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtable.html

Comment: @Mike, лучше оформите в виде ответа.